# Dynamic not specific, all_load invalid?

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, flags

In my Xcode projects I keep getting many warnings stating the following:

> warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC

Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?